# grammar is accepting too much

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am new to [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/) and try to get along with some very first and simple examples (using antlr-4.8). This seems to me like a stupid newbie problem but I could not find an appropriate answer (actually I do not even know how to phrase the question other than this lousy title). Sorry for that!

My grammar looks like this.

```
grammar ExprTest;

expr    :   compareExpr
        |   NUMBER
        ;

compareExpr
        :   (GT | GE | LT | LE) NUMBER
        ;

NUMBER  :   [0-9]+;
GT      :   '>';
GE      :   '>=';
LT      :   '<';
LE      :   '<=';
```

It pretty much does the job and recognizes `17`, `>15` and `<=22` and it complains correctly with `token recognition error` at an input of `@34`.

What I do not understand is the input `34>`. There is no complaining and it is matched as `(expr 34)`.

Why isn't there a recognition error with the last greater-than character (which is obviously in the wrong position)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input `34>` does not produce a token recognition error, because there are two expected tokens in it: `NUMBER` and `GT`. And the parser also has no problem with it because the rule:

```
expr    :   compareExpr
        |   NUMBER
        ;
```

happily accepts the `NUMBER` token and then stops, leaving the `GT` token alone.

If you want to force the parser to consume all tokens in your stream, you should *anchor* your parser with the built-in `EOF` token:

```
expr : (compareExpr | NUMBER) EOF;
```

after which the input `34>` *will* produce an error.